# Passing Python strings to Mallet for topic modelling

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, topic-modeling, mallet

I'm building a corpus of texts harvested alongside some metadata from HTML with BeautifulSoup. It would be really helpful if I could call Mallet from within Python, and have it model topics from Python strings, rather than from text files in a directory. That way I could put the n keywords located by Mallet into each file.

I get a message saying that Mallet has been recognised when I run:

```
from nltk.classify import mallet
from subprocess import call
mallet.config_mallet("malletdir/mallet-2.0.7/bin")
```

But I haven't had any luck with the next steps, and am not even sure if Mallet accepts anything other than saved files.

I have not been able to turn up any documentation that I can really understand. Has anybody seen digestable documentation for this? (The NLTK book doesn't get into Mallet). I would also be happy to learn of any other means of topic modelling within Python that I could operationalise without a really deep knowledge of Python.

Sorry, this is my first rodeo.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are still looking for a solution: Gensim (a Python topic modeling/machine learning packet) has a wrapper for Mallet which is easy to use and well documented. [Here](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html) are some Gensim tutorials and a specific [tutorial](http://radimrehurek.com/2014/03/tutorial-on-mallet-in-python/) for the Mallet wrapper. You may also want to read some installation instructions (mostly the part about setting Java memory) [here](http://programminghistorian.org/lessons/topic-modeling-and-mallet) and then you'd be ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

I once tried implementing [Mallet](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/mallet.html) with an NLTK project and I too ran into dead end after dead end. I think that main thing to keep in here is Mallet is Java based while NLTK is written in Python.

You already knew that but my point is for me personally I struggled with mixing the technologies because I do not have a strong background with Java. I've received the same feedback from coworkers about Mallet with Python, "Be ready to spend a lot of time debugging."

Since then I've been using the [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) library for Python. It is aimed at machine learning more generally, not directly for NLP but can be used for it quite nicely. It comes with a very large selection of modelling tools and most of it seems to rely on [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) so it should be pretty fast. I've used it quite a bit and can say that it is very well written and documented.

I don't want to discourage you from using Mallet, especially just because I said so. But if you are open to alternatives, I think you will find that when building projects with NLTK it's far easier to using Python modules since it itself is written in Python. I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I read up a little on sklearn, but getting things working is just as bad, at present---I'm on OSX Lion, and I can't get Scipy or matplotlib to install properly! Assuming I can, does this method seem about right to you: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/topics_extraction_with_nmf.html ? Sorry to bug you---this is a fairly minor component of a thesis, overall, and I'd prefer not to head down too many dead ends.

Comment: Yes, this is a great example.